# Laravel 9 show images on PDF from Blade view

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I'm using laravel 9 with php 8.2 on docker image.

When I try to set a img on my blade template the img don't show. I have been use a dompdf to create this using workCertification.blade like template from workCertification function.

I have already create the **php artisan storage:link**

Thanks.

The images are in public/img/*

[image]

- CONTROLLER

```
 # 2 CREATE TEMPLATE AND SEND INFROMATION.
   $html = view('payroll/workCertification', ['certification' => $certification, ])->render();
   # dompdf OPTIONS
   $options = new Options();
   $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
   $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
   # STAR DOM MODEL
   $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
   $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
   $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
   $dompdf->render();
   # RETURN PDF 
   return $dompdf->stream();
```

- VIEW

```
 <body>
        <!-- DIFERENT OPTION TO CALL IMG-->
        <div>

   
        <img src="<?php echo URL::asset('img/logo.png') ?>">
        <img src="{{asset('storage/img/logo.png')}}"/>
        <img src="http://localhost:8000/img/logo.png" />
        <img src="{{ url('storage/img/logo.png') }}"/>
        <img src="{{ asset('./img/logo.png') }}" />
        <img src="{{ url('/storage/img/logo.png') }}" />



        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h2>CERTIFICACIÓN</h2>
        </div>
</body>
```

- RESULT

[image]

Comment: If you set the URLs statically with localhost and no port, does it work? I have an issue with Homestead/Snappy/wkhtmltopdf because I access the site through port 8000, but wkhtmlpdf works inside the VM where the webserver is running on port 80. I've resigned myself to never having images when testing locally, but it's fine when the code goes into production.